# RockMongo error on connecting MongoHQ database

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

When I try to connect on MongoHQ database with RockMongo i get error: Execute failed: db assertion failure. Database is created, login data is ok, and i tried login on both ways from:

http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/configuration

and i get the same error.

When i try insert samo data in the same database on the way given in

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

everything is ok. Please help!

Comment: It sounds stupid, but did you try restarting `mongod`, then connecting again?

Comment: Please tell me detailed what you mean on trying restarting mongod. I am beginner in usage MongoDB and RockMongo.

Comment: `mongod` is the system service that actually runs the database. I think [this article](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo) will expain the gory details of conquering it better than I'll ever do. )

Comment: Should I post it as answer, I wonder. ) Actually my advice was influence by several similar questions in other community, maybe it'll be useful for somebody else... Yet on the other side it's offtopic here, I suppose.

Comment: If you are connecting to a MongoHQ DB you shouldn't have a mongod on your local system. I think you'll find it is likely you are still not connecting to MongoHQs mongod.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if Rockmongo gives that error when the background instance was restarted for any reason and there weren't any config changes such as name of the server or port or change in any user credentials, then simply refresh (F5) on the browser a few times and the data should flow in for Rockmongo once again.